# How to select option in HTML select using TAL in ZPT?

Tags: html-select, template-tal, zpt

I got the following drop-down list - `SELECT` element - construction in my `ZPT` template:

```html
<select id="record_selector">
    <option tal:repeat="record view/records" tal:attributes="value record/id">
        <span tal:replace="record/name"></span>
    </option>
</select>
```

How make it possible to have selected `OPTION` which value is equal to one from the corresponding `view` property (i.e. for example, `OPTION` tag `value` ==  `view/currentRecordId` then make it `selected`).

Comment: Why not just use a different <option tal:condition="..."> for each of checked and unchecked options?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [sdupton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187507/how-to-select-option-in-html-select-using-tal-in-zpt/18206654#comment26663098_18187507)'s clue, I got the following solution:

```html
<select id="record_selector">
    <tal:block tal:repeat="record view/records">
        <option tal:condition="python: record['id'] != view.recordId" 
                tal:attributes="value record/id"
                tal:content="record/name">
        </option>
        <option tal:condition="python: record['id'] == view.recordId"
                tal:attributes="value record/id"
                tal:content="record/name"
                selected>
        </option>
    </tal:block>
</select>
```

`TAL` conditionals are awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution here: https://old.zope.org/Members/peterbe/DTML2ZPT/index.html#example14

This still works with Zope 5.3 on Python 3.

```html
<select id="record_selector">
    <option
        tal:repeat="record view/records"
        tal:attributes="
            value record/id;
            selected python: record['id'] == view.currentRecordId">
        <span tal:replace="record/name"></span>
    </option>
</select>
```